# Not able to view Open Sans consistently in all three browsers FF, Chrome and IE latest versions

Tags: html, freemarker

Not able to view the 'Open Sans' google font across all browsers. The 
  only place its getting applied is in Safari and iOS devices. Verified with 
     'Litmus' for cross browser compatibility issues. In every browser it is 
      showing different font.

Also tried applying the code for respective default font ignore(like eg: 
     san-serif !important). Still same inconsistent output - 'Open Sans' Font 
      not getting applied.

Note: I have to use online link as this is part of email template. I cant 
     use font downloaded on my server.

I m applying below code as described by many on stack-overflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />

<!-- [if !IEMobile] -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-
scale=1" />
<!-- [endif] -->

<title>ABC Co.</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>

<!-- [if mso] -->
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<!--  [endif] -->

</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100% !important; -ms-text-size-
adjust: none;" -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; bgcolor="#ffffff">

<style type="text/css">
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700);
    body, table, h1, h2, p, span { font-family:'Open Sans', sans-
    serif!important; Helvetica !important; Arial !important; 'Times New 
    Roman' !important; }
</style>


...Content
</body>
</html>
```

As some suggested on this forum, I tried the above code keeping it in the 
    header style section also. But no change, same output.

Also tried href instead of import url in style tag.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if replacing the doctype declaration to HTML5 will change anything (`<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`) - But you can't use webfonts in HTML email template AFAIK

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I tried your suggestion. But same no change. I m expecting it to work atleast on all three major browsers. I mean if I click the link view as web page atleast it should show me correct font.

Comment: Does your website use SSL? Because if the address is `https://...` then you should load the fonts from `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css....` (note the https)

Comment: @Alon I tried making changes keeping in mind regarding ssl. Results are same. Looks like the 'Open Sans' being non-web safe font, this issue persists, if it i. As mentioned I cant download the font on server